# Storyboard imageview in a tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview, storyboard

I have an imageview inside a tableview cell of tableview. what i want to achieve is it should resize the imageview according to the image it contain dynamically.Currently  I have it  like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this same exact issue not long ago.

First, you should set image content mode to Aspect Fit, **BUT** it is not enough.

You will have to change imageView's aspect ratio constraint every time you want to load a new image. Basically, what you need to do is:

1. Get your image's width and height
2. Calculate aspect ratio `let aspectRatio = Float(image.height) / Float(image.width)`
3. Use that aspect ratio to create a new aspect ratio constraint for your image view.

This is a copy-paste (with added comments) of my code where I managed this issue. Hope it will help you.

```
    // aspectRatioCnst is IBOutlet reference to aspect ratio constraint I've set on mainImageView in Storyboard
    if let aspectRatioCnst = aspectRatioCnst {
        aspectRatioCnst.isActive = false
    }
    let aspectRatio = Float(imagePost.height) / Float(imagePost.width)
    aspectRatioCnst = NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: self.mainImageView,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height,
        relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal,
        toItem: self.mainImageView,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width,
        multiplier: CGFloat(aspectRatio),
        constant: 0)
    if let aspectRatioCnst = aspectRatioCnst {
        self.mainImageView.addConstraint(aspectRatioCnst)
        aspectRatioCnst.isActive = true
        self.mainImageView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
    if let image = imagePost.loadedImage {
        self.mainImageView.image = image

    } else if let imageURL = URL(string: imagePost.fileURL) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            // UIImage extension with downloadedFromURL method
            UIImage.downloadedFromURL(url: imageURL, withCallback: { (image) -> (Void) in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.imageLoadingActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                    self.mainImageView.image = image
                    self.imagePost?.loadedImage = image
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: what if the image is downloading asynchronously. Then how will the code know the height and width of the the image??

Comment: It's a good point. I thought I won't have to copy that part too, but since you asked, I updated my answer. P.S. In the response JSON which is pointing to image URL, I get the height and width of the image, so I don't have to calculate it.

Comment: Basically, I first download all images metadata where I have height and width of every image and URL where I can download the image. And then when I dequeue table view cells, I just asynchronously download images. Hope I clarified it a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

First set your bottom content a height like this,

[image]

Then set your image constrains like this,

[image]

Then do this in your code,

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        let imageNew  = UIImage(named: "test") //Set your image here
        let oldWidth = imageNew!.size.width
        let scaleFactor = tableView.frame.size.width / oldWidth

        let newHeight = imageNew!.size.height * scaleFactor
        let newWidth = oldWidth * scaleFactor

        //Finally to get cell size just add the bottom part height for othercontents to ImageHeight here
        let CellSize = CGSize(width: newWidth, height: (newHeight + 40))
        return CellSize.height

    }


     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        cell.NewImage.image = UIImage(named: "test")
        return cell

    }
```

You should get somthing like this,
[image]